# Failed to create directory "/var/www/html/frontend/runtime/cache": mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to deploy yii-2 application on digital ocean droplet(CentOS 7) with Nginx web server. I have set the www folder perimission to:

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

and ownership is tested with www/apache user. But still getting permission denied to create cache folder:

```
Exception – yii\base\Exception
Failed to create directory "/var/www/html/frontend/runtime/cache": mkdir(): Permission denied
Caused by: yii\base\ErrorException
mkdir(): Permission denied
in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php at line 628
```

Please guide me, am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: CentOS does come with enabled selinux by default, can you check by running `getenforce` ?

Comment: I ran this command. Getting getting "Enforcing". What i have to do ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should give: `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/frontend/runtime`

Answer (score 0):

You need to let selinux know what directories you're going to allow the http process to write to. think of it as another set of permissions.
use [chcon](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) to set or change these permissions

here's my quick list of dirs a typical yii app needs to write to

```
chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/*/frontend/runtime
chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/*/backend/runtime
chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/*/console/runtime
chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/*/frontend/web/assets
chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/*/backend/web/assets
```

note that the wildcard (`*`) in the above paths applies to all directories in www

project specific paths that need write access (file/image upload folders) need to be applied individually

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/some-project/uploads/*
```

you could also read more about contexts [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files)

if it's a new setup, you will probably need to set the following [flags](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-booleans-configuring_booleans) for things to work properly

```
setsebool -P allow_httpd_anon_write 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

---

if all of that just isn't your cup of tea you ca enable permissive mode

```
setenforce 0
```

Comment: I did all these changes but still getting the same error.

Comment: can you share the output of `ls -lZ /var/ww/frontend`